# Generalization of Noether Normalization Lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I am currently working through the exercises of the book *Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra* by Siegfred Bosch. I find some of the exercises from this book **very** hard (just for context, I'm actually a graduate math student). As an example, I am trying to solve the following problem from this book, which is a generalization of Noether Normalization Lemma.

> Let $\varphi:R\to A$ be a monomorphism of rings equipping $A$ with a structure of an $R$-algebra of finite type. Assume that $R$ is an integral domain and that $ra=0$ for $r\in R, a\in A$ implies $r=0$ or $a=0.$ Show  there exists a finite set of polynomial variables $X_1, \ldots, X_d$ such that $\varphi$ extends to a monomorphism $\varphi': R[X_1,\ldots, X_d] \hookrightarrow A$ and that the latter becomes finite when localized by the multiplicative system generated by a suitable element $s \in R-\{0\}.$

I first tried to mimic the proof of the original Noether Normalization Lemma given in that book (which relies strongly on a preceding lemma whose proof is somewath involved and I didn't understand it at all) but I failed. I really have no clue of how to proceed. Can you please help me to develop a proof for this exercise?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to apply Noether normalization to $Q(R) \to A \otimes_R Q(R)$?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Unfortunately the book mentioned above covers the tensor product a rings until the chapter 4 (I'm currently on the chapter 3)

Comment: Ok but you know localizations, right? Tensoring with Q(R) is just localizing at R - {0}.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Oh. I see. Let me try this approach and if I achieve to an answer I will post it below